# Install Linux on Chromebook with failed TPM module?

Tags: linux-mint, boot-loader, chrome-book, tpm

I have a Samsung XE303C12 Chromebook which apparently has a failed TPM module. It won't boot into ChromeOS, and when I try to recover the OS, I'm told that an error has occurred. I hit `Tab` and the `recovery_reason` is `0x05 TPM error in read-only firmware`.

My questions are:

1. At this point it looks like a lost cause to get ChromeOS back on here, and I'd rather something like LinuxMint anyway. So that's what I'd like to attempt. Can I even install Linux when the TPM module is malfunctioning?
2. I can't put the Chromebook into Developer/Unverified mode since I can't boot into ChromeOS. I've tried to hit `Esc+Refresh+Power` and then `Ctrl+D` and then `Enter` but it just reboots to the same failure screen. Do I have to overwrite the bootloader to do this? I'm okay with that.
3. Is this a lost cause since the TPM module is (apparently) dead?

Comment: Note: I've ordered a replacement TPM module but I'm not convinced that 1) I can de/re-solder it effectively, or 2) it will fix the problem. That will be a last resort.

Comment: TPM module received. No clue what to do now! I assume it has to be initialized with some key from the old module...

Comment: I believe if the netbook is also to be sold in China then there has to be a way to disable the chip even if it's TPM 2.0. You might have a hard time finding out the correct CMOS position though.

Comment: Not an answer about installing Linux, but this will probably fix the tpm error: just turn the chromebook on, wait until the error screen comes up, leave it on like this for 30 seconds, then turn it off. Wait a few seconds then repeat. Within 20-25 cycles of this, the Chromebook should start booting properly again. I used to work at a helpdesk in a school district that used Chromebooks, and this worked for me all three times I encountered that tpm error, though I always lost count of how many cycles it took.
A link from Google product forums about this as well: https://support.google.com/chrome